# Excel VBA: Create a table from the permutation of other two

Tags: excel, vba

I want to generate new entries as two tables say how.
It could be like a vlookup but I need more than one "result entry" per "original entry"

I would like to know if there is a single formula, or I should use macros or maybe even python.

I really also didn't know how to search this, maybe a link would be useful.

This example will explain better than me what I need.

**Example:**

Table 1. SALES

[image: Table 1]

Table 2. Tells which primary materials are used in each product (product components)

[image: Table 2]

Result table: Tells the amount of primary materials by product and client

[image: Table 3]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Macros and access.
I know that I should program something like this:
1) for each sale give the product
2) search entries with that product in table 2 
3) append those entries in the new table 3
4) multiply by the sale's units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Excel Power Query if you are looking to keep things simple.

We use Office 365 in our office and we frequently use Power Query for things like this.

I tossed your data into two tables and configured the power query to output the aggregated data per client, per material.

The output will be updated if you modify the tables and click the refresh button on the data tab.

[Excel example (using Office 365)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jMIX.png)

Comment: It works well with Office 2013 and up. I think it was there in 2010 but I could be wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help, It's really helpful especially if your data comes from an external data source like sql server, or even another Excel file.